# laravel search filter

Tags: php

Пишу фильтр поиска на laravel, имеется больше 20 полей, можно ли как то все эти поля аппаратно проверять и в зависимости от того имеются ли они или нет, выполнять запрос?
Если писать нативно, то на выходе получится огромная куча говнокода, можно ли как то аппаратно првоерять GET?

Comment: "Аппаратно" точно не выйдет, процессоры не поддерживают никаких GET. и вообще ничего не подозревают о интерпретируемых языках типа php